# jQuery - Without using a plugin, how do I make a clicked link scroll horiz to the position of it's child element who's ID matches the link's anchor?

Tags: jquery, scroll, hyperlink

I have a carousel style element that uses next/previous buttons to navigate through the divs inside the container. The container has a fixed width, and the overflow is hidden. I'd like to use links to scroll the div to the position of the container's child element who's ID matches the link's anchor.

The link markup:

```
<div class="time-range">

   <ul id="time-nav">
      <li><a href="#1" id="1pm" class="time-chooser">1pm</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2" id="2pm" class="time-chooser">2pm</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3" id="3pm" class="time-chooser">3pm</a></li>
      <li><a href="#4" id="4pm" class="time-chooser">4pm</a></li>
      <li><a href="#5" id="5pm" class="time-chooser">5pm</a></li>
      <li><a href="#6" id="6pm" class="time-chooser">6pm</a></li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

The carousel markup:

```
<div class="pane-container">
   <div class="carousel-pane" id="1">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
   <div class="carousel-pane" id="2">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
   <div class="carousel-pane" id="3">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
   <div class="carousel-pane" id="4">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
   <div class="carousel-pane" id="5">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
   <div class="carousel-pane" id="6">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
</div>
```

I am using the jQuery library, I just don't want to use an extra plugin for this piece of functionality.

Regular Javascript would be ok too...

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking to rewrite the plugin.  Why don't you just use it?

Comment: The functionality for the carousel I'm using is written custom and therefore does not include options for links - I just wanted to augment that. Thought there would be a simpler way to just scroll to a div with fewer lines of code rather than use a plugin that has code I didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

If the panes are fixed width you can use simple math:

```
$("#time-nav").delegate("a","click",function(e) {
   var $link = $(e.target);
   $("#pane-container").animate({scrollLeft:parseInt($link.attr("id")) * YOUR_WIDTH});
});
```

If the width varies, you'll need to grab the offset.  This requires that your parent is positioned

```
$("#time-nav").delegate("a","click",function(e) {
   var $link = $(e.target);
   var offset = $("#pane-container").find("div[id=" + parseInt($link.attr("id")) + "]")[0].offsetLeft;
   $("#pane-container").animate({scrollLeft:offset });
});
```

Comment: Hi Neil, So far the code gets the content in the right spot, but it doesn't scroll into place.